# Turn on a relay for a specified amount of time after the press of a momentary switch

Tags: arduino-uno

This is my first time programming an Arduino. I have a small brushed DC motor that I want to control using a 5V relay, which in turn is connected and controlled by the Arduino.

What I would like to do is this: Command the relay to turn ON for a specified amount of time, after pressing a momentary push button, then turn OFF once the specified amount of time has passed.

Once that's done, I would like it to reset itself, so to speak, so if I press the push button again it does the same thing.

My current script is:

```
const int relay = 8; //motor relay
const int button = 9; //momentary trigger switch

int status = true;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once: 
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (digitalRead(button) == true) {
    status = !status;
    digitalWrite(relay, status);
  } while (digitalRead(button) == true);
  delay(500);
}
```

What it currently does is: if I push the push button once, it will command the relay ON until I press the button again, which then turns the relay OFF until further input.

I know that I should use the millis() function for the timer functionality, but for the life of me I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work thus far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to ask the IDE to auto-format your code (Ctrl-T). Maybe you could see that what you wrote doesn't match your intention.

Comment: Yes I adapted some code I found online in order to test if everything was setup correctly hardware wise. I now want to add the functionality I described in my original post but I can't figure out how. I have tried to adapt code from similar use cases to mine but I just can't get them to work properly, if at all.

Comment: your code is `if button is pressed then change the state of the relay, and if the button continues to be pressed, then wait .5 sec` .... you want `if button is pressed then turn on relay, wait .5 sec, turn off relay`

Comment: Okay, so the code probably needs to be scrapped. I know that I must do the following:

1. De bounce the button
2. Use millis() preferably to time the relay, so it can be turned off after a specific amount of time

However, I have been unable to figure out how.

Comment: there is no need to debounce because the first contact closure results in a 500 ms delay ... the contact bounce will never get detected ... just change the few lines of code inside the `if` block

Comment: `I have been unable to figure out how` ... it is literally spelled out in english ... `if button is pressed then turn on relay, wait .5 sec, turn off relay` ... you already have all the necessary command lines ... just rearrange them